# Accessing data from multiple documents

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble getting data to display. Only the first element in the XML document is showing up. I need a list of contributors to show up grouped by the amount of money contributed. Here is my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="persons" select="document('persons.xml')" />

<xsl:key name="contAmount" match="donation" use="@amount" />
<xsl:key name="pinID" match="donation" use="@pin" />
<xsl:key name="personID" match="person" use="@pid" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>Lighthouse Charitable Trust</title>
     <link href="money.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <h2>Contribution Report</h2>
   <p>Total Donation Amount: 
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//donations/donation/@amount), '$###,000')" />
  </p>
  <p>Total Donors:
    <xsl:value-of select="count($persons/persons/person)" />      
  </p>

 <p>
   <xsl:variable name="cid" select="//donations/donation/@pin" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$persons">
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/firstName" /> &#160;
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/lastName" /> <br />
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/street" /> <br />
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/city" />,
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/state" /> &#160;
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/zip" /> <br />
     <xsl:value-of select="key('personID', $cid)/phone" /> <br />
   </xsl:for-each>
 </p>

 <a href="#{generate-id()}">
 <xsl:value-of select="person" />
</a> 

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide the following missing and important information: a small source XML document and the exact wanted result for this document. Also, explain the rules that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `persons` variable contains a document, which is a single node with children, not a list of nodes.

When you use `<xsl:for-each>` later in your stylesheet, you're only iterating through a 'list' containing this one document node. It's difficult to tell exactly without seeing your source documents, but it looks like you probably need to specify `$persons/persons/person` instead of just `$persons`. This may also make your use of `key('personID', $cid)` superfluous, but it's difficult to be sure without more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now the first person's info is showing up 60 times, so I guess my key's reference is still broken somehow. Here's the source I'm working with:
<persons>
<person pid="p1">
   <firstName>David</firstName>
   <lastName>Olson</lastName>
   <street>5133 Oak Street</street>
   <city>Delphi</city>
   <state>KY</state>
   <zip>89011</zip>
   <phone>(532) 555-8981</phone>
</person>
</persons>